# use dotfuscator after build time

Tags: asp.net, dotfuscator

how can I use dotfuscator for my dlls in web application after build time so when I publish my website it will contain the encrepted dlls instead of the old ones?

Answer (score 1):

Use Post-build event command in VS 2008.

Right click on your csproject, choose properties, go to build event, then inside the post build event command line, type in the following batch command:

1. [dotobfuscator command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227284(VS.80).aspx), and
2. the command to copy the files to the website (i.e,  `copy %encrypteddll% %destination%`) .

The copy command should be something like this:

```
copy "D:\EncriptionFolder\BusinessEntitesLayer.dll" "D:\wefaq\SocialProject\SocialProject\bin\BusinessEntitesLayer.dll"
```

Or alternatively, you can use [NANT](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) or other build tools to automate your build steps.

Comment: I tried to write the following on post build event command :
copy %D:\EncriptionFolder\BusinessEntitesLayer.dll% %D:\wefaq\SocialProject\SocialProject\bin\BusinessEntitesLayer.dll%
but it gave me error when build the project:
the command ... exites with code 1

Comment: I solved the previos problem now after I published the website it can't find the login page what to do?